# Out of Memory on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csXub.png)

I am trying bind the data on index page some data gets display but after few seconds this error comes. I am using .net core 6 with oracle

I have tried all the option given in learn more and also tried to google the but I was not able to find solution

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var unitcode = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UnitCode");
        CommonViewModel.EmpMstslist = new List<EmpMst>();
        try
        {
            CommonViewModel.EmpMstslist = GetAllEmp();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return View(CommonViewModel);
    }
    public IEnumerable<EmpMst> GetAllEmp()
    {
        var unitcode = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UnitCode");
        IEnumerable<EmpMst> empList;
        string query = "select EM_PNO,EM_NAME,EM_PASS,EM_STATUS,EM_HNAME,UNIT_CD from emp_mst where     UNIT_CD ='" + unitcode + "'";
        DataTable table = _context.GetSQLQuery(query.ToString());
        empList = (from DataRow dr in table.Rows
                   select new EmpMst()
                   {
                       EmPno = Convert.ToString(dr["EM_PNO"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["EM_PNO"]) : ""),
                       EmHname = Convert.ToString(dr["EM_HNAME"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["EM_HNAME"]) : ""),
                       EmName = Convert.ToString(dr["EM_NAME"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["EM_NAME"]) : ""),
                       EmStatus = Convert.ToString(dr["EM_STATUS"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["EM_STATUS"]) : ""),
                       UnitCd = Convert.ToString(dr["UNIT_CD"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["UNIT_CD"]) : ""),
                       EmPass = Convert.ToString(dr["EM_PASS"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["EM_PASS"]) : "")

                   }).OrderByDescending(x => x.EmName).ToList();

       

        return empList;
    }


<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="HrmsGrid">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th> Unit Code </th>
                                    <th> Employee Personal No. </th>
                                    <th> Employee Name      </th>
                                    <th> Employee Pass      </th>
                                    <th> Employee HName     </th>
                                    <th> Employee Status    </th>
                                   
                                    <th class="table_cell">Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>


                            <tbody>
                             
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.EmpMstslist)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitCd )</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmPno)</td>                                     
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmName )</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmPass)</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmHname)</td>
                                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmStatus )</td>                                        
                                                <td>
                                                    <a asp-area="FASADM" asp-controller="FASM014" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-emp="@item.EmPno" asp-route-UnitCode="@item.UnitCd" class="addnewitem glpicon @Model.Edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="far fa-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Edit" onclick="SHOW_TR_Function('traddpanelEdit','traddpanel')"></i></a>
                                                    <a class="delete glpicon @Model.Delete" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" onclick="divShow('/FASADM/FASM014/DeleteConfirmed?emp=@item.EmPno&&unitcd=@item.UnitCd');"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"></i></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                   

                                  
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
```

t**he amount of data returned by query is 22358 rows.** I have also tried adding this to `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />` web.config file.

Comment: Do you really need to show them all on a single page? Also note, ordering on the query itself is far more efficient than ordering on the retrieved list.

Comment: Your code has SQL injection issue and please remove unnecessary `Convert.ToString` two times on the same value

Answer (score 0):

These are many rows. Try to load only a part of it and add more, if they are needed.

You could do this in the SQL-Statement:

```
select EM_PNO,EM_NAME,EM_PASS,EM_STATUS,EM_HNAME,UNIT_CD 
    from emp_mst where     UNIT_CD ='unitcode' 
OFFSET     0 ROWS   -- skip 0 rows
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY; -- take 10 rows
```

Same is possible with [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying)

```
        query.Skip(0).Take(100)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.EmName).ToList();
```

But as mentioned in the comments: Remove the Convert.ToString(...) and address the SQL injection problem.

---

As mentioned you have to show all the data at once. That's not recommendable, but well...

The OutOfMemory exception happens in Chrome and not in the application. You could try some things, to get a grasp what happens:

1. Try Chrome in incognito mode
2. Try Firefox/Edge/etc.
3. Reset Chrome, delete user profile

Two other things you could try:

1. In the view don't use a table, but insert just the content one column of every  row. Something like this:

```asp
    <div>
        @foreach(var row in CommonViewModel.EmpMstslist) 
        {
            <div>@row.EmPno</div>
        }
    </div>
```

2. Write the result in a simple txt file and check the size.

Comment: I have modified the code but the requirement is to show all the data in one go . I have removed unnecessary Convert.ToString

 EmPno =  Convert.ToString ( dr["EM_PNO"]  != DBNull.Value ? dr["EM_PNO"] : ""),

Comment: Where does the OutOfMemory exception happen? While rendering or while getting it from the database?

Comment: error comes on chrome after some data gets displayed. it is not the database exception

Comment: Perhaps thats more a Chrome problem. Please see my edit.